# Missing Credentials: Compute Engine and App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-compute-engine

I have a project in Google Cloud, with Google Compute Engine APIs activated.

The problem is that the "Compute Engine and App Engine" credential field is completely missing from "Developers Console -> APIs & auth -> Credentials". I have not been able to find any document explaining how to generate it, probably because as I read from unofficial sources, it's done automatically.

Because of this missing credential, I'm stuck at the authentication phase and cannot use the services I need, so, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I am having exact same issue (Missing Compute Engine and App Engine credentials) for a project I created last week. I tried to "Create" the "Cloud Integration" from appengine console but that is failing (retried it few times). Because of this my appengine project is not able to connect to cloud storage, throwing InternalError. Is there any other way to create these credentials.

Answer (score 1):

So, you are looking for credentials which looks like:

```
CLIENT ID      1234.apps.googleusercontent.com
EMAIL ADDRESS  1234@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

Try to go to "Overview" section and look for:

```
Project ID: bla-bla Project Number: 1234
```

Where instead of 1234 you should see your project number. If it will not work -- go to appengine.google.com, select your app, Application Settings and try to create Cloud Integration.
[image]

Comment: Those are exactly the credentials I'm looking for, the problem is that what "Overview" section shows is not complete: there's the "CODE" part missing `CLIENT ID 1234-CODE.apps.googleusercontent.com`, and the same for the `EMAIL ADDRESS` field. Creating the Cloud Integration did not change anything.

Comment: By creating a service account you will get an client ID which will look like `1234-CODE.apps.googleusercontent.com`.

Comment: I need not only the `CLIENT ID` and `EMAIL ADDRESS`, but also the `client_secret` and `client_x509_cert_url`, provided by the JSON file associated to my missing _Compute Engine and App Engine_ credentials. I didn't notice that Cloud Integrations returns: _An error occurred when creating the project. Please retry._

Comment: Why do you need client_secret for service account? `client_secret` and `client_x509_cert_url` are included in JSON file generated by creating a Client ID for web application.

Comment: Ok, I did it before reading your reply and this seems to work. By the way, I still don't understand the reason why this Credential field appears in some of my projects and not in others.

Comment: Alessio, are you able to connect to GCS from AppEngine now ? If yes, could you give more pointers on how, especially what type service account you created and if you are passing any param related to the service account to cloudstorage client lib.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is a google cloud product issuse , contact google support .